# Coldfusion query show hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a scenario where I need to show a button which onclick will expand and show the rest of the values. Values are coming from a query. If the values are more than 8 for example, then the button needs to show. I know this sounds pretty simple, I have tried something like below, but is there a better way (more dynamic) to do it?

```
 <cfif getqry.recordCount neq 0>
        <div id="topics" class="posts margin-bottom-40">
          <div class="headline"><h2>News </h2>
       <cfoutput>  
         <cfloop query="getqry" startrow="1" endrow="8">
          <div class="btn-group hover_drop_down"> <a href="/abc.cfm?newsid=#nid#" class="btn" type="button"> #News_item# </a> </div>
         </cfloop>

          <cfif getqry.recordCount gt 8>
           <div id="collapse-news" class="collapse-inline collapse">
                  <cfloop query="getqry" startrow="9" endrow="#getqry.recordCount#">
                            <div class="btn-group hover_drop_down"> <a href="abc.cfm?newsid=#nid#" class="btn btn-news dropdown-toggle" type="button"> #news_item# </a> </div>
                 </cfloop>
            </div>

         <button class="btn btn-kw-ml MoreLess" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="##collapse-news">See More</button>
         </cfif>
        </div>
        </cfoutput>
     </cfif>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $('.MoreLess').click(function(){
              var $this = $(this);
              $this.toggleClass('MoreLess');
              if($this.hasClass('MoreLess')){
                     $this.text('See More');                 
              } else {
                     $this.text('See Less');
              }
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-line solution. However, you could simplify the code *a bit*, by using the `query.currentRow` variable to control the generation of the container `div` tag. Also, no need for both cfloop and cfoutput.

```
<cfset hideAtRow = 9>
...
<cfoutput query="getQry">

      <!--- start container for "show more" --->
      <cfif getQry.currentRow eq hideAtRow >
        <div id="collapse-news" class="collapse-inline collapse">
      </cfif>

      <!--- assign classes based on current row number --->
      <cfset btnClass = currentRow gte hideAtRow ? "btn btn-news dropdown-toggle" : "btn">
      <div class="btn-group hover_drop_down"> 
         <a href="/abc.cfm?newsid=#nid#" class="#btnClass#" type="button"> #News_item# </a> 
      </div>

      <!--- on last row, close "show more" container if needed --->
      <cfif getQry.currentRow eq getQry.recordCount and getQry.currentRow gte hideAtRow >
        </div>
        <button id="testButton" class="btn btn-kw-ml MoreLess" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="##collapse-news">See More</button>
      </cfif>

</cfoutput>
...
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this approach.

In ColdFusion

```
<cfsavecontent variable = dynamicContent>
coldfusion and html code goes here
</cfsavecontent>

<div id="stuffToToggle">
something here, maybe
</div>
```

In javascript

```
<cfoutput>
var #toScript(dynamicContent, "stuffFromColdFusion")#
</cfoutput>
function toggleStuff () {
if (something)
document.getElementById("stuffToToggle").innerHtml = stuffFromColdFusion;
else
document.getElementById("stuffToToggle").innerHtml = somethingElse;
}
```

The syntax might not be perfect.  I'm just showing you the general idea.